# Dual bar line chart is not getting generated with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, collections, highcharts

Dual bar line chart is not getting generated with dynamic value.
While printing those value in console, proper values are getting retrieved but while providing the same array graph is not getting constructed.

```
var WeekArray = [];
var Performance = [];
var availability =[];
WeekArray = "${WeekArray}";
Performance = "${Performance}";
availability = "${availability}";
$(function () {

    console.log(WeekArray + "::::: "+Performance +"::::::"+availability)
    Highcharts.chart('dual_chat', {
        chart: {
            marginRight: 50, // like left
            marginLeft: 60,

        },
        xAxis: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            title: {
                text: 'Months',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            categories:['W32', 'W33','W34', 'W35', 'W36',' W37', 'W38', 'W39', 'W40', 'W41', 'W42', 'W43', 'W44', 'W45', 'W46']
            //categories:WeekArray
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 88,
            max: 100,
            tickInterval:2,
            alignTicks: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            lineWidth: 3,
            title: {
                text: 'Availability (%)'
            }
                },
            {
            min: 14,
            max: 20,
            alignTicks: false,
            endOnTick: false,   
            tickInterval:1, 
            lineWidth: 3,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Performance (Sec)'
            }
        }],

        series: [
        {
            color:'#ed7626',
            name:"Availability",
            data: [99.86, 99.57, 99.99, 99.89, 98.97, 97.98, 99.99, 99.99, 99.15, 99.99, 99.99, 99.97, 99.99, 99.99, 99.36]
            //data: availability

        },
        {
            color:'#80bfff',
            name:"Performance",
            data: [13.27, 13.43, 13.24, 13.36, 15.27, 16.48, 17.03, 15.49, 15.72, 16.06, 16.53, 16.25, 16.85, 17.01, 16.96],
            //data: Performance,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
```

Please help me how to generated the graph with dynamic value.
console output is:

```
['W32', 'W33', 'W34', 'W35', 'W36', 'W37', 'W38', 'W39', 'W40', 'W41', 'W42', 'W43', 'W44', 'W45', 'W46']::::: [13.27, 13.43, 13.24, 13.36, 15.27, 16.48, 17.03, 15.49, 15.72, 16.06, 16.53, 16.25, 16.85, 17.01, 16.96]::::::[99.86, 99.57, 99.99, 99.89, 98.97, 97.98, 99.99, 99.99, 99.15, 99.99, 99.99, 99.97, 99.99, 99.99, 99.36]
```

Comment: this is not java please remove the tag.

Comment: WeekArray, Performance, availability are strings, not arrays. Change this part of code: WeekArray = "${WeekArray}";
Performance = "${Performance}";
availability = "${availability}";